# How to generate a set of symbols with certain subscripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I would like to define a set of symbols in the following way:
I have three different subscripts: [1,3,5]
The following symbols must be generated:
a_11,a_13,a_15, a_31, a_33, a_35, a_51, a_53, a_55

How do I do this efficiently? So without defining all symbols separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sympy import Symbol
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

symbol_indices = set([])
for a,b in combinations_with_replacement([1,3,5],2):
    symbol_indices.add( (a,b)  )
    symbol_indices.add( (b,a))

[Symbol(f'a_{a}{b}' ) for a,b in symbol_indices]
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
from itertools import product

l1 = [1, 3, 5]
result = [f"a_{tuple_[0]}{tuple_[1]}" for tuple_ in product(map(str, l1), repeat=2)]
```

Outputs

```
['a_11', 'a_13', 'a_15', 'a_31', 'a_33', 'a_35', 'a_51', 'a_53', 'a_55']
```

For me

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to import other stuff than "sympy", you can use a nested list comprehension.

```py
ind = (1, 3, 5)

sympy.symbols(['a_{}{}'.format(n, m) for n in ind for m in ind])
```

---

I think `itertools` is just hiding the real logic behind algirithms. I personally prefer to write code instead of using some heavily nested function with unreadable arguments.

Answer (score 0):

**without any library, for loop:**

```
l= [1,3,5]
print (list("a_{}{}".format(*x) for x in list((x,y) for x in l for y in l)))
```

output:

```
['a_11', 'a_13', 'a_15', 'a_31', 'a_33', 'a_35', 'a_51', 'a_53', 'a_55']
```

**with itertools:**

```
from itertools import product
l= [1,3,5]
print (list("a_{}{}".format(*x) for x in list(product(l,repeat = 2))))
```

output:

```
['a_11', 'a_13', 'a_15', 'a_31', 'a_33', 'a_35', 'a_51', 'a_53', 'a_55']
```

NOTE:

```
list((x,y) for x in l for y in l) 
# equivalent to:
list(product(l,repeat = 2))
```

> **itertools.product()**
>
> This tool computes the cartesian product of input iterables.  It is
>   equivalent to nested for-loops.  For example, **product(A, B)** returns
>   the same as **((x,y) for x in A for y in B)**.